# retaining values of radio buttons

Tags: php

I am a php programmer .I have an image rating page ,in which it displays the image gallary with radio buttons once selected and submitted ,the image button values go to the table .when I retrieve the images they are rendered properly , however they do not show the previous radio button rating selection.

My question is how to retain the most recent radio selections , when images are fetched into the browser.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure what your options are but it would be something like this;

```
<input type="radio" name="image_option" value="1"<?php $_POST['image_option'] == 1 ? ' checked="checked"'; ?> />

<input type="radio" name="image_option" value="2"<?php $_POST['image_option'] == 2 ? ' checked="checked"'; ?> />

<input type="radio" name="image_option" value="3"<?php $_POST['image_option'] == 3 ? ' checked="checked"'; ?> />
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to set the "checked" attribute for the appropriate radio buttons that you want to be selected.

Answer (score 1):

if you want to default select then use "Checked".
and if you want to checked on resent selective button. then on submit time, store radio button value in session and when browser get request after submission radio value then retrieve session value and apply checked on previous select radio button.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you need:

1. The value in the database to match
2. The value of the radio button itself

Which will allow you to:

Compare the database value (DBV) with the radio button value (RBV) and set it as checked if the comparison comes back as true.

The variables below are:

$ar_rvbs = the array of radioset values (strings or booleans, usually) you are going to loop through and check against the stored DBV.

$value = the value of each item in the radioset value array

$attrval = the stored value for radio button. it doesn't necessarily have to be in a database. you could use the post method to pass it from one page to the next.

$checked = if the DBV matches the RBV when the loop goes through, this will be set to the string "checked" otherwise it is just an empty string.

```
function makeRadioSet($ar_rvbs,$attrval=[DBV] /*A*/
  {

  foreach ($ar_rvbs as $value)
     {
      $checked = '';                          /*B*/
      if ($attrval==$value)                   /*C*/
      $checked = "checked";                   /*D*/
      echo '<input type="radio" name = "fieldname" value = "'.$value.'" '.$checked.'>';
     }
  }
```

/*A*/ Pass the list of RBVs as an array and the DBV as a variable

/*B*/ Set checked to an empty string because that will be the default for all the radio buttons in the set except the one that matches the DBV

/*C*/ Compare the DBV to the current RBV being processed by the loop from the RBV array

/*D*/ If the comparison from step C returns true, make the checked string available for insertion into the input element

The echo takes care of generating each radio set option and making sure the one that matches the DBV has "checked" in the input element tag

Answer (score 1):

You can use in following method

```
@{
     string MaleChecked = "";
     string FemaleChecked = "";
     if(@Model.Gender=="Male")
        {
              MaleChecked = "Checked";
        }
     else
        {
              FemaleChecked = "Checked";
        }
   }
```

if form use

```
Male<input type="radio"  name="Gender" id="rdoGender" value="Male" @MaleChecked>
Female<input type="radio"  name="Gender" id="rdoGender1" value="Female" @FemaleChecked>
```

Answer (score 0):

after reload the page you have to add the attribute checked to the radio buttons you have to check.
The correct syntax is:

```
<input type="radio" name="foo" id="bar" value="1" checked="checked" />
```